# Transpose equality seems incorrect

Tags: alloy

The equality *s.~r is equal to r.s* on page 63. of Software Abstractions seems incorrect. I believe *s.~r is equal to ~(r.~s)* is the correct statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement, s is a set, so ~s isn't a legal expression.